# how to create an audio clip from a video file using command line?

Tags: sound, command-line, video

I would like to create an audio clip from a video file using the command line, since this is in a terminal text-only Ubuntu 11.04 server system. I would like to select the starting and finishing time for the clip from the video file, something like:

```
create_clip video.file -from 00:10:00 -to 01:20:10 -o clip.file
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my [blog post](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/flv-audio-extraction.htm) about that:

```
$ ffmpeg -i youtubemusicvideo.flv -vn -acodec libvorbis result.ogg
```

Selecting the start time can be done with option `-ss hh:m:ss`, and the length of the resulting clip can be configured `-aframes 1234`. Have a look at the ffmpeg man page for more details.

Comment: thanks, how can I define clips with start-end inside the file?

Comment: If you're happy with Vorbis as the output format, you can use [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php) afterwards to split the .ogg file at the appropriate points.

Comment: mp3splt result.ogg 00.10 01.20 works perfectly, thx